# Rails 'where' with association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I'm new to rails and I have a join table containing a user id, team id and a number, basically a user can have many teams, teams can have many users, and a team belongs to a tournament, those numbers should be unique per tournament, what I'm trying to do is get all the rows which contains teams from a specific tournament, basically something like

```
 MyJoinTable.where(team.tournament_id: self.team.tournament_id)
```

But that doesn't work, any advice on how to make this

Comment: will you elaborate more with your exact models and associations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you can do this :

`Team.joins(:tournaments).merge(Tournament.where(id: self.team.tournament_id))`

Comment: Thanks, I already bypassed it by getting all memberships, then keeping only those which tournament id matched the current one.

Comment: If I understand, you made one request to your database to get ALL the memberships and then you iterate over it to select only those that you want ? In that case, that is not optimized at all and you may face hudge performance issues as your database will grow up. I really recommend you to perform your operations directly in the database (either with my solution or pure SQL).

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have

```
class Team
  has_and_belongs_to_many :members
  belongs_to :tournament
end

class Member
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teams
end

class Tournament
   has_many :teams    
end
```

Then `tournament.teams` will yield all the tournament's teams. 
Or `Team.where(tournament_id: an_id)` will also work if you don't have the tournament instance.
Joining/including the members table is just as easy to get all the tournament's members.

The has_and_belongs_to_many should be replaced with a has_many :through relation if your join table contains more data then the ids of the joined tables. See [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association).